# JMeter GUI - How to clear specific outputs from Listener

Tags: jmeter

When I debug and use JMeter GUI with listener(s),

I sometimes want to remove certain outputs, as the last 5, or failed ones, but keep all other outputs

Can I select output to be clear ? because I can't mark using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> some outputs and I don't want to clear all output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is no option to remove certain output from the specified listeners what you can do is, you can write the result set in csv sheet from the listener and manipulate the result set according to your need.

This is the simple solution that you can try for your problem.

Comment: I wanted in GUI, but it seems there isn't any option

Comment: In listeners there is a section on top "results to file and read from file". Just provide the path to the file in which you want to write the results as shown in the listener.